# error: no browser selected to run against, but i mentioned it in .testcafe.json

Tags: testing, configuration, automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have created .testcaferc.json, I mentioned the browser and src in it. so I should be able to run tests without putting this in the command line.
But it does not seem to be reading my config file from the project folder.

```
{
    "src": "c:/Testcafe/Login.js",
    "browsers": "firefox",
    "reporter": {
        "name": "html",
        "output": "reports/report.html"
    },

    "takeScreenshotsOnFails": true,
    "screenshotPath": "/screenshots/"
}
```

**Actual:**
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
ERROR No browser selected to test against.

Type "testcafe -h" for help.

**Expected:**
I should not ask for browser and test file parameter as both are provided in config file.

Comment: Your TestCafe version is v1.0.0 or later? And are you running TestCafe from the folder that contains the configuration file?

Comment: i am using testcafe from folder where configuration file is available.       
Using windows 10,                                                                                                               
>testcafe -v
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
0.20.5,

Answer (score 2):

The configuration file is a feature added in v1.0.0. If you upgrade from 0.20.5 to 1.0.0 or later, you will be able to use the configuration file for your tests.

Release Notes:
https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Comment: if i check version when i am in folder c:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm> then version it shows is 1.4.3, but when i am in another folder and check version with command testcafe -v then i get 0.20.5

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling TestCafe completely and then reinstalling? Sorry, I'm not sure how you'd get two versions.